# What's "Signature Edition"?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations, version-differences

I intend to pre-order Assassin's Creed: Revelations from GameStop, the title was followed by "Signature Edition". What does it mean? And, why can't I pre-order digital version (so I can download it and all the bonus), GameStop says it's not available in my location (Vietnam). But I can still pre-order non-Digital version.

Comment: That depends. What game are you looking at?

Comment: You need to ask GameStop why you can't pre-order the digital version, there is probably a good reason that they are restricted from doing that. It is another question on it's own...

Comment: @Anna Lear: I intend to pre-order Assassin's Creed: Revelation: http://www.gamestop.com/pc/games/assassins-creed-revelations-signature-edition/91021 . I don't give game name because last time, my topic was closed becaused I give exactly game name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally it means "We really love you, please love us back with extra money/promotion/etc.?"  Same idea as a Limited Edition where you might get extra swag along with the game.

I have Window 7 Signature Edition, which is just Ultimate in a fancy case and I think I got a deck of playing cards and a poster with it or something.  Same idea but your disc will be a game :P and Anna's right that you need to give us the game name in order for us to tell you specifics.

**Edit:** AC:R has the following in the Signature Edition:

> The Signature Edition will grab pre-order investors a bonus singleplayer mission, an exclusive multiplayer character, weapons capacity upgrades, an animated short film and an Assassin's Creed: Revelations original game score soundtrack

<sub>http://www.joystiq.com/2011/06/09/assassins-creed-revelations-signature-edition-with-gamestop-pr/</sub>

Comment: I intend to pre-order Assassin's Creed: Revelation: gamestop.com/pc/games/… . I don't give game name because last time, my topic was closed becaused I give exactly game name.

Comment: @W.N. It looks like your other question was closed because you were asking about the pricing, and shopping advice is off-topic.  Sticking to the details of what specific versions contain is perfectly fine, though :)

Answer (score 0):

A signature edition is kind of like a collector edition; they are made for loyal fans as kind of a signature from the author, in the form of special features like:

- A game box of higher quality and art.
- Including exclusive content; in-game as well as posters/book/artwork...

As Anna Lear mentions; this depends from company to company, game to game.

So seach what the extra signature edition has to offer you and consider if it's worth buying it...

*I once saw an under cover police agent wear a HL2 T-shirt, he must be a great fan of Half-Life 2...*

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Matthew, the "signature edition" is a collector's edition of a game.

It says right on the page what comes with the Signature edition. On top of the normal game, this deluxe edition of Assassin's Creed also comes with:

- A Bonus Singleplayer Gameplay Mission
- An Exclusive Multiplayer Character
- 3 Weapon Capacity Upgrades
- An Animated Short Film
- The "Assassin's Creed Revelations" Original Game Score Soundtrack

Also, your last question wasn't closed because you mentioned a specific game, it was closed for being too localized, explained [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/25709/assassins-creed-revelations-pre-order-price-difference) or [in the FAQ](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#close).

Comment: Yes, I thought it's "plain" bonus for anything that a pre-order must have. So "Signature Edition" means it includes bonus like these?

Comment: Yes, signature editions of games come with bonuses, though the bonus is different for other games.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. But I think Matthew Read's answer is more details. So, just a +1 vote, please forgive me.